# dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore.fetch() onComplete handler cannot access global variables?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I wrote a function to get the number of items in a list. It takes as input the primary key (list_pk) of the list whose items we want to count. It then queries the data store for all list items that have "list" equal to list_pk and counts them...

```
function getListLength(list_pk){

    // Data store of list items
    var store = getStore();   

    dojo.global["length"] = -1;

    // Get all list items that belong to the list 
    store.fetch({
        query: {list : list_pk},
        onComplete: function(items, request){
            dojo.global["length"] = items.length;
            console.log("onComplete() length: " + dojo.global["length"]);
        }
    });

    console.log("after onComplete() length: " + dojo.global["length"]);
}
```

With a list length of 5, the above displays:

```
onComplete() length: 5
after onComplete() length: -1
```

So it correctly counts the number of items, but it fails to update the global variable "length". Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct behavior. `store.fetch` is an asynchronous call. When `onComplete` is called, the `dojo.global["length"]` will be updated. If you try to get the global variable after `store.fetch`, the `onComplete` may not be called yet, so you still get the initial value.

Just put the code to use `dojo.global["length"]` inside of `onComplete` function.